# Can you specify the DocHeight of a webpage, so as to exclude the comments section?

Tags: java, javascript, google-analytics

I'm currently trying to set up a scroll depth tracker for my blog, so that I can tell how much of it people are reading. The problem is that the current code includes the comments section - and I don't really care whether people read that or not.

I've noticed this in the code used to determine how far a reader has scrolled:

`function calculateMarks(docHeight) {`

`return {`

'25%' : parseInt(docHeight * 0.25, 10),

I just wonder: is there any way I can modify the definition of docHeight, so that I can exclude the comments section from it?

Answer (score 0):

The validity of this really depends on the sturucture of your page, but assuming that the comments make up the entire bottom of the document this would work.

To get a more accurate measurement you would have to consider the position of all the elements on the page, so this is really just a very basic theoretical example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function calculateMarks(docHeight) {
        var commentsContainer = document.getElementById('myCommentsContainersId');
        var docHeightSansCommentsContainer  = docHeight - commentsContainer.offsetHeight;

        return {
            '25%' : parseInt(docHeightSansCommentsContainer * 0.25, 10),
        ...    
</script>
```